# CScript Error: Execution of the Windows Script Host failed - Rails rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am deploying rails project on heroku. When I use rake assets:precompile it gives following error -

```
rake aborted!
CScript Error: Execution of the Windows Script Host failed. (0x800A0007)

(in c:/Rails Projects/sheets_vip_rails/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [c:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe c:/Ruby193/bin/rak...]

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hey @vajapravin have you found any solution to this?