# Ruby on Rails Rake assets:precompile error - Command failed with status (1) - CScript Error: Execution of the Windows Script Host failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, asset-pipeline

Okay so time after time we've all seen question about Rake assets:precompile error. I've tried multiple methods, I looked at the following SO question [Ruby on Rails Rake assets:precompile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464544/ruby-on-rails-rake-assetsprecompile-error) and tried multiple methods of even doing the following: `config.assets.compile = true` and then running `rake assets:precompile --trace RAILS_ENV=production`. However I noticed that when I tried to do the following:

`rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` I got the following error:

> rake aborted!
>   CScript Error: Execution of the Windows Script Host failed. (0x800A0007)
>
> C:\Users\home\Desktop>cd MIUK_Portal
>
> C:\Users\home\Desktop\MIUK_Portal>rake assets:precompile
>   RAILS_ENV=production C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake assets:precompile:all
>   RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets rake aborted! 795: unexpected
>   token at
>   'C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Temp\execjs20121221-5484-1atk9yx.js(2, 3)
>   Microsoft JScript runtime error: Out of memory
>
> '   (in
>   C:/Users/home/Desktop/MIUK_Portal/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
>
> Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary (See full trace by running
>   task with --trace) rake aborted! Command failed with status (1):
>   [C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe C...]
>
> Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile (See full trace by running task with
>   --trace)

Has anyone encountered this issue? How do you overcome this?

**Update**

Okay apparently from looking at the error it clearly is stating that

> :\Users\home\AppData\Local\Temp\execjs20121221-5484-1atk9yx.js(2, 3)
>   Microsoft JScript runtime error: Out of memory

So I'm now wondering how to resolve this? Any ideas? Further to this I noticed that someone did encounter the similar issue: [CS Script issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292514/cscript-error-execution-of-the-windows-script-host-failed-rails-rake-assetsp) but this was unresolved:

So I am asking if anyone out there has had the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by transferring the project into a Linux environment (Ubuntu) and running the `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`. It appeared to work, I believe this sort of issue is something to do with windows. If starting any kind of development to do with RoR stick to Linux.

Answer (score 1):

This was what I did, and it worked for me. I installed node.js first in my system, and then ran the following command `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`.